# Combinatorial argument for $\sum _{n=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}y^n = \frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{k+1}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

[These](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/combinatoricsweb/generate.pdf) course notes give the following identity as (**8**) under subsection 1.1.3 with the following explanation(with a typo; the corrected form is from *generatingfunctionology* identity 1.31):

> Sometimes a problem that does not seem to be a multi-index problem can
> be reformulated to be of the correct form. Consider, for instance, the
> problem of finding the generating function for binomial coefficients
> $\binom{n}{k}$ for fixed k as a function of n. The trick is to think of each
> set as being listed in order, from 1 to n. Take a set B with 2k + 1
> points. There is a bijection between multi-indices on B and subsets
> with k elements. The multi-index corresponding to a subset counts the
> number of elements between each of the elements of the subset and also
> counts each element.

$$\sum _{n=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}y^n = \frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{k+1}}$$

I couldn't follow the reasoning in that paragraph; could I get a detailed, step-by-step explanation or a different combinatorial argument for this identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We utilize a toy version of [combinatorial class](https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/online/slides/AC01-OGFs.pdf).

- **Definition.** For each countable set of words $\mathcal{A}$, we define its generating function $\mathcal{A}(x)$ by
  $$ \mathcal{A}(z) = \sum_{a \in \mathcal{A}} z^{|a|}, $$
  where $|a|$ is the length of the word $a$.
- **Observation.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be two countable sets of words, and assume the following property holds:

  > **Property.** Each possible concatenation $ab$ of words $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and $b \in \mathcal{B}$ uniquely defines a new word. That is, $a_1b_1 = a_2b_2$ with $a_1, a_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ implies $a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = b_2$.

  By collecting all possible concatenations, we form a new set of words $\mathcal{A}\cdot\mathcal{B}$:
  $$ \mathcal{A} \cdot \mathcal{B} = \{ ab : a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B} \} $$
  Under the assumption, it follows that
  $$ (\mathcal{A}\cdot\mathcal{B})(z) = \sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}, b\in\mathcal{B}} z^{|ab|} = \sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}}\sum_{b\in\mathcal{B}} z^{|a|+|b|} = \mathcal{A}(z)\mathcal{B}(z). $$

  Obviously this observation generalizes to an arbitrary finite number of concatenations under the uniqueness assumption extending the above property.

---

Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of all words of alphabet $\{\mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b}\}$ containing exactly $k$ letters $\mathtt{b}$. We compute $\mathcal{C}(z)$ in two ways and establish OP's identity.

**1.** Each word of length $n$ in $\mathcal{C}$ has exactly $n-k$ $\mathtt{a}$'s and $k$ $\mathtt{b}$'s. The number of all such words of length $n$ is precisely $\binom{n}{k}$, and so,

$$ \mathcal{C}(z)
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\{ c \in \mathcal{C} : |c| = n \}| z^n
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} z^n. $$

**2.** On the other hand, it is easy to see that each word in $\mathcal{C}$ uniquely factors into the concatenation of $k+1$ sequences of $\mathtt{a}$'s and $k$ letters $\mathtt{b}$'s. For example,

$$ \mathtt{aaababbaa} = \mathtt{a}^3\mathtt{b}\mathtt{a}^1\mathtt{b}\mathtt{a}^0\mathtt{b}\mathtt{a}^2. $$

To make use of this observation, we write $\mathcal{A} = \{ \mathtt{a}^i : i \geq 0\}$ for the set of all words of alphabet $\{\mathtt{a}\}$, and let $\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathtt{b} \}$. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}
= \{ \mathtt{a}^{i_0}\mathtt{b}\mathtt{a}^{i_1}\mathtt{b}\cdots\mathtt{b}\mathtt{a}^{i_k} : i_1, \ldots, i_k \geq 0 \}
= \underbrace{\mathcal{A} \cdot \mathcal{B} \cdot \mathcal{A} \cdot \mathcal{B} \cdots \mathcal{B} \cdot \mathcal{A}}_{\text{total $k$ $\mathcal{B}$'s}}.
\end{align*}

Hence, the corresponding generating functions satisfy the relation

$$ \mathcal{C}(z)
= \underbrace{ \mathcal{A}(z) \mathcal{B}(z) \mathcal{A}(z) \mathcal{B}(z) \cdots \mathcal{B}(z) \mathcal{A}(z) }_{\text{total $k$ $\mathcal{B}(z)$'s}}
= \mathcal{A}(z)^{k+1}\mathcal{B}(z)^k. $$

Now the desired conclusion follows by noting that $\mathcal{A}(z) = \sum_{i\geq 0} z^i = \frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\mathcal{B}(z) = z$.

Comment: A very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Start by:

$$\frac1{1-y} = 1 + y + y^2 + \cdots = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty} y^\ell$$

Now,

$$\frac1{(1-y)^{k+1}} = \left(\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty} y^\ell\right)^{k+1} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left|\mathcal I_{m,k}\right|x^{m}$$ where $\mathcal I_m := \left\{\left(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_{k+1}\right) \in \mathbb N^{k+1}: \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\ell_j = m\right\}$ the set of multi-indices that sum up to $m$.

Let count the number of elements in the set $\mathcal I_{m,k}$ it is not difficult to see that $\mathcal I_{m,k}$ has the same number of elements as $\mathcal J_{m,k} := \left\{\left(r_1,\ldots,r_{k+1}\right) \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}^{k+1}: \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}r_j = m + k + 1\right\}$ which has the same number of elements as $\mathcal K_{m,k} := \left\{\left(s_1,\ldots,s_{k+1}\right) \in \mathbb N^{k+1}: 1 \le s_1 < s_2 < \ldots < s_{k+1} = m+k+1\right\}$ which is equivalent to choose $k$ integer elements from $\left\{1,\ldots, m+k\right\}$. This proves that: $$\left|\mathcal I_{m,k}\right| = \binom{m+k}{k}$$

can you finish the proof?

Comment: Multiply by $y^k$, you obtain a series with terms $y^{m+k}\binom{m+k+1}{k}$ which is not quite right, this doesn't match what appears after substituting $n=m+k$.

Comment: You have to choose $s_1,\cdots,s_k$ from $\{1,\cdots,m+k\}$ as $s_k<s_{k+1}=m+k+1$. I performed this minor edit. +1 this is nice, I had no idea what the text was talking about until reading this